# Create household head based on age and member id

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation, data-management

I have a data frame of household members containing 3 integer columns, 'hid', 'sub', and 'age'. I'd like to create a new logical variable in the data frame called 'hh' representing the household head, defined as follows:

1. If there is only 1 member in the household, then the value is TRUE,
2. If there are 2 or more members in the household, then the household head is the one who is aged between 18 and 65 (inclusive) and has the smallest subject id ('sub') among those aged between 18 and 65.
3. If there are no members in the household aged between 18 and 65, then the household head is the one with the smallest subject id.

There must be 1 and only 1 household head per household.

My data looks something like this:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 3
     hid   sub   age
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     1    75
 2     1     2    55
 3     2     1    35
 4     3     1    69
 5     3     2    72
 6     4     1    69
 7     5     1    15
 8     5     2    17
 9     5     3    42
10     6     1    72
```

And I'd like the result to be like this:

```
> result
# A tibble: 10 x 4
     hid   sub   age hh   
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>
 1     1     1    75 FALSE  # Not 18-65 & there is another aged 18-65 within this household.
 2     1     2    55 TRUE   # Aged 18-65 and the smallest sub id within this household.
 3     2     1    35 TRUE   # Only 1 in this household.
 4     3     1    69 TRUE   # Not aged 18-65, but no other member is and smallest sub id.
 5     3     2    72 FALSE  # Not aged 18-65, and not the smallest sub id.
 6     4     1    69 TRUE   # Only 1 in this household.
 7     5     1    15 FALSE  # Not aged 18-65 and others in this household qualify.
 8     5     2    17 FALSE  # Not aged 18-65 and others in this household qualify.
 9     5     3    42 TRUE   # Aged 18-65 and the smallest sub id among those aged 18-65 within this household.
10     5     4    62 FALSE  # Aged 18-65 but not the smallest sub id among those aged 18-65 within this household.
```

Thank you!

---

```
d <- structure(list(hid = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5), 
                      sub = c(1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4),
                      age = c(75, 55, 35, 69, 72, 69, 15, 17, 42, 62)), 
                 row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work? For things like this where the logic can be convoluted, it can be helpful to actually draw a representation of the code by hand, like a decision tree, to tease it apart. It can also be helpful to make temporary variables to keep track of the different conditions, e.g. number of people in the household, is the person 18–65, etc, rather than trying to combine all the logic into one step

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `arrange` the data in such a way that the first row of each group is the `hh` value you are looking for.

```
library(dplyr)

d %>%
  arrange(hid, !between(age, 18, 65), sub) %>%
  mutate(hh = !duplicated(hid)) 

#     hid   sub   age hh   
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>
# 1     1     2    55 TRUE 
# 2     1     1    75 FALSE
# 3     2     1    35 TRUE 
# 4     3     1    69 TRUE 
# 5     3     2    72 FALSE
# 6     4     1    69 TRUE 
# 7     5     3    42 TRUE 
# 8     5     4    62 FALSE
# 9     5     1    15 FALSE
#10     5     2    17 FALSE
```

`!between(age, 18, 65)` would arrange the data keeping the individuals aged 18-65 first before others who are outside the range.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option

```
library(dplyr)
d %>% 
    group_by(hid) %>%
     mutate(hh = if(n() == 1) TRUE else if(n() > 1 & 
         !any(between(age, 18, 65))) age == min(age) else
        age == min(age[between(age, 18, 65)])) %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 x 4
     hid   sub   age hh   
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>
 1     1     1    75 FALSE
 2     1     2    55 TRUE 
 3     2     1    35 TRUE 
 4     3     1    69 TRUE 
 5     3     2    72 FALSE
 6     4     1    69 TRUE 
 7     5     1    15 FALSE
 8     5     2    17 FALSE
 9     5     3    42 TRUE 
10     5     4    62 FALSE
```

---

Or another simplified option is

```
d %>% 
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
    arrange(hid, sub, age) %>%
    group_by(hid) %>% 
    mutate(hh = age == coalesce(age[between(age, 18, 65)][1], 
           first(age))) %>% 
    ungroup %>%
    arrange(rn) %>%
    select(-rn)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 x 4
     hid   sub   age hh   
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>
 1     1     1    75 FALSE
 2     1     2    55 TRUE 
 3     2     1    35 TRUE 
 4     3     1    69 TRUE 
 5     3     2    72 FALSE
 6     4     1    69 TRUE 
 7     5     1    15 FALSE
 8     5     2    17 FALSE
 9     5     3    42 TRUE 
10     5     4    62 FALSE
```

Comment: Where is the 'sub' variable?

Comment: Hi @akrun. Suppose the ages of the members in the last house (#5) are 15, 17, 62, and 42. I want the 3rd member to be the household head. Based on the smallest value of the 'sub' variable, not the minimum age. Thanks. :)

Comment: @Edward can you please update your post with a new example. The second solution does order by the subid

Comment: Yes, the second solution works fine. The first one, not so fine. :P Thank you!!

Comment: @Edward Thanks, I missed the `sub` part.  Your input data showed in the post is slightly different than the `dput`

Answer (score 2):

An option with `case_when`,
each case_when is translating your conditions 1 to 3 into code:

```
library(dplyr)

d %>% 
    group_by(hid) %>% 
    mutate(hh = case_when(max(sub) == 1 ~ TRUE,
                          max(sub) > 1 & 
                              between(age, 18, 65) &
                              sub == min(sub[between(age, 18, 65)]) ~ TRUE,
                          max(between(age, 18, 65)) < 1 & 
                              sub == min(sub[max(between(age, 18, 65)) < 1]) ~ TRUE,
                          TRUE ~ FALSE))
```

Output:

```
     hid   sub   age hh   
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>
 1     1     1    75 FALSE
 2     1     2    55 TRUE 
 3     2     1    35 TRUE 
 4     3     1    69 TRUE 
 5     3     2    72 FALSE
 6     4     1    69 TRUE 
 7     5     1    15 FALSE
 8     5     2    17 FALSE
 9     5     3    42 TRUE 
10     5     4    62 FALSE
```